# Excel and C#: how to verify if data has been changed by user

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, excel-addins, vba

Is there an efficient/effective way of verifying if a table of data has been modified/altered? I was thinking of calculating some hash out of the data and save the hash has metadata associated to the range. How would you achieve a requirement such as this?

Comment: Is this for an add-in?

Comment: Yes, I would be doing it from a VSTO C# add-in.